# Custom Layout with child views

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I am getting an error on this. Cannot figure out how to use child views in my custom view (Relative layout).

```
   <RelativeLayout >   

    <com.xxxxxx.FavouriteImageView
        android:id="@+id/favorite_status"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:clickable="true" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/favourite_iv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/yellow_star"
            android:clickable="false" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/favorite_spinner"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:clickable="false" />

    </com.xxxxxxxx.FavouriteImageView>
```

```
public class FavouriteImageView extends RelativeLayout{

ImageView star;
ProgressBar spinner;
boolean isFavorite;

Context context;

public FavouriteImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    this.context= context;
    findChildViews();}

public FavouriteImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    this.context= context;
    findChildViews();
}

public FavouriteImageView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    this.context= context;
    findChildViews();}


private void findChildViews(){

    star = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.favourite_iv);
    spinner = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.favorite_spinner);
}
```

}

The problem is I keep on getting NPE when ever I try to use `star` or `spinner`. Dont know how to use the child views.

Comment: They're not yet present in the constructor. Why don't you just call this code in your activity?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot find these views in constructor. The child views are not yet added to the parent.

For your case, you can override the addView() method and do the same :

```
@Override
public void addView(View child, int index, LayoutParams params) {
    super.addView(child, index, params);
    switch (child.getId()) {
    case R.id.favourite_iv:
        spinner = (ProgressBar) child;
        break;
    case R.id.favorite_spinner:
        star = (ImageView) child;
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using this in your custom layout class:

```
@Override
public void addView(@NonNull View child, int index, ViewGroup.LayoutParams params) {
    super.addView(child, index, params);
    if (child.getId() == R.id.favourite_iv) {
        star = findViewById(R.id.favourite_iv);
    } else if (child.getId() == R.id.favorite_spinner) {
        spinner = findViewById(R.id.favourite_spinner);
    }
}
```